# Exiting do/while loop without using a break

Tags: c++, loops, break, do-while

I have a school problem with a program that works like this:

The string the user can enter is either a phone number or `X` (if they want to exit). The inner loop is full of functions that check the phone number and make sure it's the correct length and format, and prompt the user to enter again if there's a mistake detected, etc.

This piece of code works fine as long as I type in phone numbers. When I type in `X`, it recognizes `X` as being something that needs to go to the inner loop to check for length and format, instead of just exiting.

I've tried many different ways to fix this, and the only thing that I can get to work is the `break` statement, which my professor does not accept.

How can I write this `do`/`while` loop without using a `break`? I placed a `cout` statement below the initial selection prompt and it shows that `X` was entered, but it still won't exit without using:

```
if(selection == "x" || selection == "X")
    break;
```

Instead it sends the X into the do/while loop to correct the format into a number `###-###-####`:

```
string selection;
do
{   
    cout << "Please select a number from the list or type 'X' to exit:  ";
    cin >> selection;
    cout << endl;

    //if(selection == "x" || selection == "X")
    //break;

    if(selection != "x" || selection != "X")
        do
        {
            checking length function
            .
            .
            .
            checking format function
        } while(argument is true);

    resultFunc(prints the phone number + billing info from the parallel array);
} while(selection != "x" || selection != "X");
```

Comment: Hint: Think about the while and if conditions for a second. If selection is 'X', what will happen? What if it's 'x'? Consider what's meant by || and walk through the conditions.

Comment: While stripping it down, you replaced C++ with English. How is that supposed to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(selection != "x" || selection != "X")
```

Needs to be:

```
if(selection != "x" && selection != "X")
```

This is a classic example of [De Morgan's laws.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) You want to know if `selection` is "x" ***or*** "X", so the opposite would be if `selection` is not "x" ***and*** is not "X".

Comment: This mistake comes from a widespread mistake in English, where people say "if `selection` is not 'x' or 'X'", when they should instead be saying "if `selection` is neither 'x' nor 'X'" (which has no direct analogue in traditional boolean operators).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I would argue that's not a mistake. It sounds like they're saying "if `selection` is not ('x' or 'X')" which, using De Morgan's Laws, would translate to "if `selection` is not 'x' and `selection` is not 'X'"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - In most cases, the "C++ is English" mistake is done like this: `if (value = 3 | 4 | 10 | 15)` meaning "is value equal 3 or 4 or 10 or 15".  Then the compiler accepts this erroneous construct and the newbie is bewildered as to why it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Indeed.

Comment: So... to Josh I thank you for the correction.  And to the English Nazi who re-wrote my question, get a life.  Seriously, you need to log off right now and go get a life.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to write the test correctly:

`while(selection != "x" && selection != "X");`

Second, instead of doing this test twice, do it only once and store the results in a boolean:

```
bool exitLoop = false;
do
{   
    cout << "Please select a number from the list or type 'X' to exit:  ";
    cin >> selection;
    cout << endl;
    if (selection == "x" || selection == "X")
        exitLoop = true;
    if ( !exitLoop )
    {
       // do stuff because input isn't X
    }
} while (!exitLoop);
```

The boolean `exitLoop` makes it clear as to what makes the loop terminate, instead of doing the repeated test for the "X" in multiple places.

In addtion, you could use the `toupper` function instead of checking for lower and upper "X":

```
    #include <cctype>
    //...
    if (std::toupper(selection[0]) == "X" )
        exitLoop = true;
```